# Backslash containing string not able find in other string

Tags: c#

I have to take the `\r\n` from the registry and compare with another string, i.e. check variable if it contains the `\r\n` or not.

Please look in this code, its not giving "TRUE" result. Please fix this issues.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string check = "324214234\r\n";
        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyRegKey\\Settings");
        regKey.SetValue("ReceiveSplChar", @"\r\n");
        string value = regKey.GetValue("ReceiveSplChar").ToString();
        if (check.Contains(value))
            Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

enter code here

```
        string SuffixValue = regKey.GetValue("ReceiveSplChar").ToString();
        if (SuffixValue != null)
            _RCVData = _SetSerialPort.ReadTo(SuffixValue);
        else
            _RCVData = _SetSerialPort.ReadLine();
        if (SerialDataEvent != null)
        {
            SerialDataEvent(_RCVData);
        }
```

its reading the character till the special character. it can be \r\n or \t or \u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** in your first assignmenet(`string check = "324214234\r\n";`) you are not escaping the special characters so `\r\n` treated as special characters and assigned string will be `324214234<newline>`, but in your second assignment statement(`regKey.SetValue("ReceiveSplChar", @"\r\n");`) you are escaping special character with `@` so the assigned string willbe intact `324214234\r\n`

**Solution :**

Replace This:

```
string check = "324214234\r\n";
```

With This:

```
string check = @"324214234\r\n";
```

**EDIT:** if you want to find the ending character/symbol of any one of (`\r\n,\n,\t`) symbols you can use following sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str="12345\t";
        string endingSymbol=GetEndingSymbol(str);            
    }

    //returns the ending symbol of a given string
    static string GetEndingSymbol(string str)
    {

        if(str.IndexOf("\r\n")>=0)
        return "\r\n";
        else if(str.IndexOf("\n")>=0)
            return "\n";
        else if(str.IndexOf("\t")>=0)
            return "\t";
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am agree with your answer, but these values are in Barcode, i have to read using Barcode Scanner. Port.ReadTo(value);

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, what what would you get from above statement and what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, so dont have idea, thanks for correcting

Comment: @AshfaqueHussain: as you said will it be only `\r\n or \t or \u` or any other special symbols?

Comment: yes it can be based on barcode, ending with a special characters. My class should read any type of ending special characters. User can change it from registry and it will store in SuffixValue when application run.  Thanks again

Comment: so you want to read the special character from barcode value and store  it in into registry for later purpose. am i right?

Comment: In registry there will be special characters \r\n or \t or \n. suppose in barcode there is \r\n then i will read the characters till \r\n...please let me know if not clear

Comment: if barcode contains \t then i have to set in registry \t. And i have to read _SetSerialPort.ReadTo("\t")

Comment: Ex: Barcode number is: "324214234\r\n" 1. i will set in registry \r\n--- 2. and then i will store in SuffixValue \r\n from registry ---3. then i will use _SerialPort.ReadTo(SuffixValue)

Comment: @AshfaqueHussain: i have edited my answer with sample code, please check .

Answer (score 2):

If you define a literal string without `@` at the beginning, then `\r\n` will be treated as special characters. On the other hand, if you use `@` before, then there is no escaping done and you get what you see (with the exception for `"`.

Try:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string check = @"324214234\r\n";
            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyRegKey\\Settings");
            regKey.SetValue("ReceiveSplChar", @"\r\n");
            string value = regKey.GetValue("ReceiveSplChar").ToString();
            if (check.Contains(value))
                Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string check = "324214234\r\n";
string value = Environment.NewLine;
if (check.Contains(value))
    Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
```

Comment: Yes it will work, thanks...but the thing is instead of \r\n can be changed..it can be \t also, sometime \u also....based on requirement we can change it from registry. and check variable value will come from Barcode its not hardcoded.